# Which quantum entropies are meaningful with respect to continuous distributions of states?

Tags: information-theory, relative-entropy, max-entropy, min-entropy

When using a quantum channel to transmit classical information, we consider an ensemble $\mathcal{E} = \{(\rho_x, p(x))\}$ consisting of states $\rho_x$ labelled with a symbol $x$ from a finite alphabet $\Sigma$, each of which is associated with a probability $p(x)$. With just this ensemble we can compute things like Holevo $\chi$ or entropy or relative entropy. If we further include a communication protocol (sender Alice tries to communicate $x$ to Bob by transmitting $\rho_x$ through channel $\mathcal{N}_{A\rightarrow B}$ with probability $p_X(x)$) we have additional quantities we can compute like channel capacity and Holevo information.

Now define the ensemble with respect to a **continuous** probability distribution $p(x)$ ($\Sigma$ is no longer finite), e.g. the classical-quantum state associated with $\mathcal{E}$ becomes
$$
\sigma_{XB} = \int_\Sigma dx p(x)  |x\rangle \langle x | \otimes  \rho_B^x, \tag{1}
$$
and the state of the ensemble becomes $\rho = \text{Tr}_B (\sigma_{XB})$. Entropy $H(\rho)$ remains well-defined, and an equation for the Holevo quantity like
\begin{align}
\chi(\mathcal{E}) &:= H(\rho)  - \int_\Sigma dx p(x)  H( \rho_x) \tag{2}
\end{align}
doesn't *seem* wrong in any obvious way. On the other hand, Shannon entropy seems to fall apart for probability densities, and $\chi$ is implicitly describing a scenario in which a continuous variable $x$ will be measured.

But some other quantities seem sketchy, e.g. conditional min-entropy seems well defined but its interpretation in terms of optimal measurements feels off. E.g. trying to adapt the operational interpretation that the conditional min-entropy maximizes the state identification probability gives something like
\begin{equation}
2^{-H_{min}(X|B)} = \max_{\{ \Lambda_B^x\}} \int_\Sigma dx p(x) \text{Tr}(\Lambda_B^x \rho_B^x) \tag{3}
\end{equation}
where the maximization is over all POVMs associating each element of $\Sigma$ with a positive operator in $A$. I do not have a good feel for whether this is a reasonable approach; I am again concerned with the idea that Bob is extracting a continuously-valued variable on his end in some way that would blow up the mutual information between his measurement and $X$ to infinity.

---

##### Question

Which information-theoretic quantities retain their operational meaning when we substitute a discrete distribution with a continuous one? References are appreciated

Comment: I think you're conflating a continuous mixture of wuantum states with a continuous random variable classically. They're not analagous in this context. The Shannon enteopy loses some of its properties when you try to extend it to a continuous distribution. Similarly, so does the von Neumann entropy for infinite dimensional systems. If you can continuously mix quantum states then you can continuously mix discrete distributions

Comment: Yes I agree with most of that. The last equation above is where I'm confused: Alice prepares a set of finite-dimensional states distributed like $p(x)$, then Bob (tries to) define a measurement for discriminating these states and calls that classical measurement outcome $M$. Now $I(X:M)$ is the mutual information between two continuous classical random variables distributed like $p(x)$ and $p(m)$. My question is whether this causes any issues in interpreting capacities or min-entropies or etc.

Comment: Ok, yes. I've not thought about it carefully but I'd imagine you're right here. Its not obvious you can take the usual quantities and just assume they apply to this case because X and M continuous in that setting.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a partial answer for the case of conditional min-entropy, due to Ref. [1] (Appendix IV.B):

Consider a fixed ensemble $\{(\rho_B(x), p(x))\}_{x \in \Sigma}$, where $p(x)$ is a probability density and each $\rho_B(x)$ is finite dimensional state on system $B$, and let $\{\Lambda(x)\}$ be a collection of bounded, positive operators on $B$ satisfying  $\int_{\Sigma} dx \Lambda(x) = I$. Then, they introduce a "window function" $w_\epsilon(z) = \mathbb{I}\{|z| \leq \epsilon\}$ and define an optimal measurement success probability as
$$
\eta^* := \sup_{\{\Lambda(x)\}} \text{Tr}\left( \int dx p(x) \rho_B(x) \int_\Sigma dx' \Lambda(x') w_\epsilon(x-x') \right). \tag{1}
$$

With max-relative entropy $D_{max}(X \Vert Y) :=\log \lVert Y^{-1/2} X Y^{-1/2} \rVert$ defined for operators $X,Y\geq 0$, the conditional min-entropy is defined
\begin{align}
H_{min}(A|B)_\rho := - \inf_{\sigma_B \in D(\mathcal{H}_B)} D_{max}(\rho_{AB} \Vert \mathbb{I}_A \otimes \sigma_B). \tag{2}
\end{align}
Then, they claim the desired equality,
$$
\eta^* = 2^{-H_{min}(A|B)_Z}, \tag{3}
$$
where $Z$ is an operator on $\mathcal{H}_{AB}$ defined as
$$
Z_{AB} := \int_{\Sigma} dx |x\rangle \langle x|_A \otimes \left(\int_{\Sigma}dx' p(x') \rho_B(x') w_\epsilon(x-x')\right). \tag{4}
$$
The operators $\{|x\rangle\}_{x \in \Sigma}$ are a collection of unbounded linear forms on $\mathcal{H}_A$, satisfying $\langle x | x'\rangle = \delta(x - x')$ (the Dirac delta). So, this almost recovers Eq. (3) from the question, with the exception of the window operator $w_\epsilon$ being used. We can then identify the expression in parentheses above with a positive operator on $B$, and then factor out its trace to recover Eq. (1) from the question: in that case $H_{min}$ plays exactly the role we're looking for.

The reason why this is a partial answer is that I still have some concerns:

- I'm not sure if the above prescription is general, whether *every* operator of the form Eq. (1) in the question could be recovered by some windowed ensemble, but its possible that the ones that can't be recovered aren't important.
- $Z_{AB}$ doesn't seem to actually be a state on $AB$ - $\text{Tr}_B(Z_{AB})$ will not be compact in general.
- Its tempting to replace $w_\epsilon(z)$ with a Dirac delta $\delta(z)$ to recover Eq. (3) exactly, but this might lead to some problems. If this doesn't work, I think that suggests certain requirements about what ensembles $\rho(x)$ we can consider.

---

[1] Johannes Jakob Meyer, et. al. "Quantum metrology in the finite-sample regime." https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.06370